# C#: Increment invoice number based on set cycles

Tags: c#, string-concatenation

I am creating incrementing invoice numbers, like so: **AABBBB1122**.

'A' and 'B' are bound to identifiers in my code.
But the digits I need to be *month* and *year*, respectively.
For example: **0821**  (august, 2021).
I don't want to connect it to a calendar in any way.
If possible I would like to define a starting date, and increment from there.

That is: ***0821*** would have to be incremented to ***0921***, ***1021***, ***1121***, ***1221*** -
before the year is incremented as well; ***0122***.

How can I do that?

**What I've got so far:**

```
string AA {
    get { return this.IdentifierA.Substring(0, 2);
    set { SetAndNotify(ref this.AA, value); }
}

string BB {
    get { return this.IdentifierB.Substring(0, 4);
    set { SetAndNotify(ref this.BB, value); }
}

string InvoiceNumber {
   get { return String.Concat(AA + BB + /* what goes here? */).ToUpper(); }
   set { SetAndNotify(ref this.InvoiceNumber, value);
```

Comment: Clarify what is problem. Because if you have stored start date, or you have function that calculates this, you can just concatenate.

Comment: Why not using  `DateTime d = new DateTime(2021, 08, 26);` to set yout Date and then format it like this `d.ToString("MMyy")`.

Comment: If you want to use month and year you have to put into your class some `DateTime` object holding the desired point in time. In your code you could then write something like `this.PointInTime.ToString("MMyy")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like a peculiar way to do invoice numbers.. You are saying you *don't* want it based on the **current date**, but to **just increment** in a MMYY style?

Well given a typical auto-increment int KEY, which goes up by 1 for each invoice, use:

```
((KEY % 12).ToString("00")+(KEY/12).ToString("00"))
```

Start KEY at **12*21+8** to start with **0821**.

.. But based on the invoice requirement I think what you must surely be asking for is:

```
(DateTime.Now.Month.ToString("00")+DateTime.Now.Year.ToString("00"))
```

Comment: picky: call DateTime.Now only once to avoid getting different answers on boundaries: 2021-12-31 + 2022-01-01 = 1222

Comment: @Chris Kuliukas, my reason for that is that the invoice might not be sent out the same month. It could be that it's sent out a day before or after, and so the number would be wrong. Could be that it's a bit peculiar.
Thank you for providing me with two ways to solve this. Appreciated!

Comment: @AmyB, thanks for your comment - would you give me an example how I could refactor the code line to take that into account?

Comment: @Chris Kuliukas, I also had to use Substring() to divide the year portion of the DateTime, as it gave me all four digits (could be a regional thing). Thanks again.

Comment: Sure thing @OleM, I would put DateTime.Now into a local variable and then refer to the local variable in the expression.

Answer (score 3):

This would be:

```cs
return string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", AA, BB, DateTime.Now.ToString("MMyy")).ToUpper();
```

or in new concatenation

```cs
return $"{AA}{BB}{DateTime.Now.ToString("MMyy")}".ToUpper();
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understood correctly your question, the objective is to parse the date from the string and generate the next id. You can then use the following logic.

```
string id = "AAAA1221";

// Extract data.
int i = Convert.ToInt32(id.Substring(id.Length - 4, 4));
int year = i % 100;
int month = i / 100;

// Perform increment logic.
if (month == 12)
{
    year++;
    month = 1;
}
else
{
    month++;
}

// Reformat key
string newId = $"{id.Substring(0, id.Length - 4)}{month:D2}{year:D2}";
```

In the case you don't want to use the previous id, you can just start the same logic with your previous value in the 'i' variable.